# Add TableViewController as SubView

Tags: ios, swift, addsubview

With may App I have 2 TableViewControllers **Inbox** and **Outbox**(each with its own custom cells) and Main ViewController **Mail** with a segment controller and UIView beneath it, what Im trying is to add the tableview controllers and switch between them on segment controller is pushed but its not working at all!

Mail ViewController :

```
import UIKit

class Mail: UIViewController, SegmentControllerDelegate {

    func indexChanged(index: Int) {
        print("index\(index)")
        switch index {
        case 0:
            container.bringSubviewToFront(inbox)
            break
            case 1:
            container.bringSubviewToFront(outbox)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
var inbox: UIView!
    var outbox : UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        inbox = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "inbox").view
        outbox = Outbox().view
        container.addSubview(inbox)
        container.addSubview(outbox)


    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        inbox.frame = container.bounds
        outbox.frame = container.bounds


    }
```

And this is the result while my Inbox and Outbox tableview is filled with data

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are currently doing is getting the `view` from the other controllers. You need to create an instance of the view controllers and keep them in memory.

This can be done by adding them as **child** view controllers:

```
    // for both inbox and outbox table view controllers,
    //  instantiate
    //  add as child view controller
    //  add its view as a subview of container
    //  finish with .didMove()

    inboxTVC = InboxTableViewController()
    addChild(inboxTVC)
    container.addSubview(inboxTVC.view)
    inboxTVC.didMove(toParent: self)

    outboxTVC = OutboxTableViewController()
    addChild(outboxTVC)
    container.addSubview(outboxTVC.view)
    outboxTVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

I've updated the project I put together for your other question with this implemented: https://github.com/DonMag/AliAdil

Answer (score 1):

rather than using a simple UIView, try using UIContainerView.

document from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use **controllers**, not just their views. (`var outbox: Outbox` instead of `var outbox: UIView`, with a proper initialization)
What you're doing here is creating an Outbox controller, taking its view (which can't operate properly without owning controller); then the Outbox controller gets released, and the view has nothing to show (Outbox controller, which is also view's data source, gets released right away).

Also I'd use a *TabBarController* to manage the child controllers

```
// Create
contentTabBarController = UITabBarController()
addChild(contentTabBarController)
contentTabBarController.viewControllers = [Inbox(), Outbox()]
// Add subview either in nib file or here; do not forget to add proper constraints as well
container.addSubview(contentTabBarController.view) 

//...

// Select inbox
contentTabBarController.selectedIndex = 0

// Select outbox
contentTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```